# Limit edismax search to a certain field value and find out matched fields on the results

Tags: solr

I have these query parameters:

```
  'q' => "iphone",
  'echoParams' => "explicit",
  'defType' =>'edismax',
  'fl' => 'name,category,score',
  'qf' =>'name_suggest_edge^50 name_suggest_exact^50  name_suggest_ngram',
  'pf' =>'name_suggest_edge^100 '
```

How can I limit the search to the `docs` that have the field value `category:phones`

An other question: is there a way to know which fields `q` was matched on`name_suggest_edge` `name_suggest_exact` `name_suggest_ngram` when the results are returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the output from debugQuery - it'll tell you exactly what fields contributed to the score of the document. Remember that multiple fields can match, so you'll have to prioritise.

You can also use highlighting to achieve something similar - it'll highlight tokens in those fields that matched your query.

Comment: I was using this `q=iphone category:phones` where it should be `q=iphone +category:phones`. operator was missing. thank you.